# How to change separate strokes lineart into stroke-less shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration, technique

I made the line art by tracing each line separately, instead of tracing fully closed shapes. Get it? not a separate stroke for each closed shape. Just a bunch strokes on separate layers meeting other strokes on separate layers.

What's the most practical to turn a lineart like this into clean closed shapes? I want to make it a 'strokless' vector without having to redo the whole thing with a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you drew something with just separate lines and now you're looking for a way to efficiently turn that mess of lines into clean filled closed shapes?

If so, then you can select all of your lines that you want to convert then click on them using the Live Paint Bucket tool (keyboard shortcut 'K'). Now start painting inside the lines with any color you like. Once you're done click the expand button, and you will have your nice, clean, closed vector shapes, all filled and ready to do your bidding.

You might want to make a copy of your line-work though before you start, in case you need them later, especially if you had an important layer structure you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you. This pretty much did it, but for some reason, it kept a very thin white line around all the edges.

Comment: Please refer to my answer to this question for the white lines issue http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45507/saving-ai-to-svg/45535#45535